# Unable to set my own Auth validation names for error message attributes in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say I have this in my view:

```
{{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
{{ Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ errors_for('email', $errors) }}
```

but instead of teh error message like:

`Your email is not valid`, I want a custom name for email e.g. email address, so in the end it will be `Your email address is not valid`

How to setum custom names for attributes in error messages.

I don't want to create a custom message, just to set a custom attribute. by attribute I mean the word `:attribute` in the error message e.g.:

`"alpha"                => "The :attribute may only contain letters."`

How to do that if I am using `Auth` component in Laravel for authentication like this:

```
public function create()
{

    if (Request::isMethod('post')) {

        $input = Input::only('email', 'password');

        $this->loginForm->validate($input);

        if (Auth::attempt($input))
        {
            return Redirect::intended('/');
        }

        // Auth::login($user);

        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('error', trans('auth.log_in_invalid_credentials'));

    }

    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::home();
    return View::make('sessions.create');
}
```

Comment: The array returned in `validation.php` may contain an `'attributes'` key. Have you tried with that?

Comment: @matpop So, how can I assign or change "email" to "email address" in the error message? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `'attributes'` array in `app/lang/en/validation.php`

```
<?php

return array(

//  ...

    "accepted"         => "The :attribute must be accepted.",
    "active_url"       => "The :attribute is not a valid URL.",
    "after"            => "The :attribute must be a date after :date.",
    "alpha"            => "The :attribute may only contain letters.",
//  ...
    "unique"           => "The :attribute has already been taken.",
    "url"              => "The :attribute format is invalid.",

//  ...

    'custom' => array(),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Custom Validation Attributes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The following language lines are used to swap attribute place-holders
    | with something more reader friendly such as E-Mail Address instead
    | of "email". This simply helps us make messages a little cleaner.
    |
    */

    'attributes' => array(
        'email' => 'email address',
    ),

);
```